# Next.js Github pages loading images problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js, github-pages

I've been trying to load photos and favicon on GitHub pages for a month now and no result at all. Even tried with a boilerplate project from `npx create-next-app@latest` and it doesn't load the images and favicon from a public folder at all. It's not the path obviously it's something from the configs, I guess, but I can't find a solution; even ChatGPT can't help.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you deploying your next.js page to gh pages? Refer this gh action workflow for example: https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/nextjs.yml (you'll need to update the variables and build commands (they are for old next.js)) -- also note that gh pages only support static pages, so many Next.js features won't work with it -- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features

Comment: Since its boilerplate - 1. git init 2. git add . 3 git commit and the rest of the steps, after that settings -> Pages -> Sources and I choose the Github actions and after that it needs to generate nextjs.yml. Done. Later i see address that the site is live. So what needs it to be configured in this nextjs.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last time. I was able to figure it out, in my case the images were in Capitalize, and GitHub pages are very sensitive about file names. :

Please go ahead and check the following:

1. Image extension should be in a small case and exact spell. E.g. jpeg and jpg are not the same, jpg and Jpg are not same, JPG and jpg are not same, etc.
2. No underscores in path names or names "_".
3. Try checking the path, proper use of "../" or "./" etc. **E.g: src="./next.svg"**
   `<Image className={styles.logo} src="./next.svg" alt="Next.js Logo" width={180} height={37} priority />`
4. Wait for some time after deploy
5. Hard refresh your browser.

I hope this will fix this.  :)

Here is my build on github pages:
[image]

Comment: Well since its generated from npx create-next-app, without touching the image extension and they are with small case in public folder the favicon.ico and vercel and next.svg the paths are correct, can you share your config.next.js i guess its something from there i tried const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '',
  },
  assetPrefix: './',
};
no luck :(

Comment: Hey dude, Can you check the bullet 3, where I have mentioned paths.

Try using "./" in your image path. It should work.
<Image
            className={styles.logo}
            src="./next.svg"
            alt="Next.js Logo"
            width={180}
            height={37}
            priority
          />

Comment: and here is my next.config.js:
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
Its the default one, I have not added anything.